# cp directories with a dot

Tags: msys

I'm using MinGW with msys under windows. I'm trying to cp a directory like this

```
$ cp -R data /d/liferay/liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1/data/
```

the data directory has paths like this

```
D:\liferay\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\data\document_library\0\0\21056.png\1.0
```

where 21056.png is a directory. After I do the cp I noticed it is not copying the directories with dots in them. Is this a bug in MinGW or am I missing something here?

Comment: I see that your solution was solved. But just to point out, this has nothing to do with MinGW (your cross-compiler).

Comment: Also you should accept your own answer to solve the question.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll accept it once I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution had to do this:

```
$ cp -R data/. /d/liferay/liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1/data/
```

Notice the extra dot

Comment: It was a silly confusion. When I executed the command in my question, the cp was copying the directory thus creating a directory data in the other data directory. That's why I couldn't see the directories with dots in them (I was trying to merge two directories with similar structure). The dot in the second command I guess is the same as * so it copies the directory contents rather than the directory itself, thus I was able to see the dotted directories. Again silly mistake on my part

Comment: In this specific case, `data/.` is exactly the same as `data`. There should be no difference whatsoever...

Comment: Janos you had me thinking so I tested again, when I do the cp without the dot it creates a directory 'data' inside wherever i put it. If I include the dot then it copies the contents only. Weird, might be something particular to msys

Comment: This is how `cp` works, it's not specific to `msys`. If you `cp data` to `some/existing/dir`, it will copy to `some/existing/dir/data`. If you `cp data/` OR `cp data/.` to `some/existing/dir`, it will copy the files inside `data/` to `some/existing/dir` without creating `some/existing/dir/data`. So you're right in that `cp data/.` and `cp data` are not the same. `cp data/.` is the same as `cp data/`. But this has nothing to do with copying directories with dots in them as in your question.